# filter data from csv using array filter not working as expected

Tags: d3.js, array-filter

My data is as follows in csv format.

Id,Title,Year,Runtime,Country,imdbRating,imdbVotes,Budget,Gross,WinsNoms,IsGoodRating
13,Alone in the Dark,2005,96,"Canada, Germany, USA",2.3,37613,20000000,8178569,9,0
38,Boogeyman,2005,89,"USA, New Zealand, Germany",4.1,25931,20000000,67192859,0,0
52,Constantine,2005,121,"USA, Germany",6.9,236091,75000000,221594911,11,1
62,Diary of a Mad Black Woman,2005,116,USA,5.6,10462,5500000,50458356,26,0
83,Fever Pitch,2005,104,"USA, Germany",6.2,36198,40000000,50071069,9,1

Im trying to filter out the data as below but none of the filtering works.

```
d3.csv("movies.csv", function(error, data) {
  // change string (from CSV) into number format
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.imdbRating = +d.imdbRating;
    d["WinsNoms"] = +d["WinsNoms"];
    d["IsGoodRating"] = +d["IsGoodRating"]
  });

  var rating0 = data.filter(function(d){ return d["IsGoodRating"] = 0});
  rating0.forEach(function(d) { console.log(d); }); 
  //the above line does not give me anything on the console
  var rating1 = data.filter(function(d){ return d["IsGoodRating"] = 1});
  rating1.forEach(function(d) { console.log(d); }); 
  //the above line gives me an output of all the records with both IsGoodRating which are 0 and 1 but the output shows as 1 which is not what the data has.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Im new to d3.js so I might be making a basic mistake.

Comment: doing the same as below is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

doing the same as below works as expected but the array filter does not.

```
  var rating0 = data.filter(function(d)
  {
    if (d["IsGoodRating"] == 0)
    {
      return d;
    }
  })
 // var rating0 = data.filter(function(d){ return d.IsGoodRating = 0}); This array filter is not working for some reason
  rating0.forEach(function(d) { console.log(d.IsGoodRating); });

  var rating1 = data.filter(function(d)
  {
    if (d["IsGoodRating"] == 1)
    {
      return d;
    }
  })
 // var rating1 = data.filter(function(d){ return d["IsGoodRating"] != 0});This array filter is not working for some reason
  rating1.forEach(function(d) { console.log(d.IsGoodRating); });
```